# Controlling window locations for files visited by Dired

Tags: window, dired

Very often I need to open a file in dired in other window and for that `dired-find-file-other-window` comes handy, but sometimes I want to open file in specific split - vertical or horizontal. So if I have:
two windows (with dired on the left)

```
  |-----------+-----------|
  | -window1- | -window2- |
  | file1     |           |
  | file1     |           |
  | file3     |           |
```

and want to explicitly tell dired to open file:

either by creating a vertical split in window1:

```
  |-----------+-----------|
  | -window1- | -window2- |
  | file1     |           |
  |-----------+           |
  | (content) |           |
```

or in window2 (which is usually a default behavior of `dired-find-file-other-window`:

```
  |-----------+-----------|
  | -window1- | (content) |
  | file1     |           |
  | file1     |           |
  | file3     |           |
```

or below window2 (by creating vertical split in window2):

```
  |-----------+-----------|
  | -window1- | -window2- |
  | file1     |           |
  | file1     |           |
  | file3     +-----------|
  |           | (content) |
```

or by creating horizontal split (adding new window to the right of window2):

```
  |-----------+-----------+-----------|
  | -window1- | -window2- | (content) |
  | file1     |           |           |
  | file1     |           |           |
  | file3     |           |           |
```

Is there a package for doing something like that? If not, can someone help me writing a function/functions?